# Tasks and activity backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have my application which has a bunch of activities (like any other application). Now I navigate between activities (populating the task's backstack) and eventually press home key to minimize the app.
I also have an alarm service which starts a particular activity. Since services can only start activities with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, I am assuming this activity will be in a new task. For extra measure I have also mentioned `launchmode="singleInstance"` in the activity's entry in Manifest.

---

### **Problem**

When the activity starts from service and finishes (I call `finish()`), the backstack of the main application gets popped back, and the last used activity comes to foreground. 
How to avoid this? I want the alarm activity to die silently without waking the main application. Since the alarm activity is in a separate task isn't it supposed to have a separate backstack too?

This doesn't happen (obviously) if the main application is cleared from recents.

Comment: "When the activity starts from service and finishes" How does this occur? Are you explicitly calling `finish()` on the activity?

Comment: Yes. I am calling finish() explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Use finishAffinity in OnBackPress of activity that is being started by service.
Please make your question more clear.

Comment: What more info do you want? I want to know what causes this behavior, more from an academic perspective. since NEW_TASK should make the activity start in an entirely new stack.